# Nodemailer & ejs - Render template from another folder

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, nodemailer

I'm using node.js, express, ejs and nodemail. I'm able to send mails with custom template if the template 'mail.ejs' is in the same folder as the controller 'contact.ejs' like this:

```
// Folder structure
controllers
    contact.js
    mail.ejs

// contact.js 
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const ejs = require("ejs");

...
const output = await ejs.renderFile(__dirname + "/mail.ejs", {
  test: 'Test'
});
...
```

It works fine ... but now I want to have the template in a different folder, but I'm struggling to call/access it. How should the ejs.renderFile(?) look like to have this folder structure:

```
// Desired folder structure 
controllers
    contact.js
views   
    mail.ejs

// contact.js 
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const ejs = require("ejs");

...
const output = await ejs.renderFile(??????, {
  test: 'Test'
});
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__dirname` tells you the absolute path of the directory containing the currently executing file.

By default, EJS is going to look for the file relative to `process.cwd()`, the directory where the Node.js process was started. `__dirname` is the directory that your JS file ( `contact.js` ) is in. If you don't want to join to `__dirname`, you need to make your paths relative to where the Node.js process is started. Which means,

If folder structure is,

```
Root
   server.js <--- EJS look for relative paths from here
   views
      -mail.ejs
```

And,

```
const output = await ejs.renderFile("/views/mail.ejs", {
  test: 'Test'
});
```

Comment: ... for some reason that's not working ... what works is renderFile(process.env.PWD + "/views/mail.ejs"

Comment: @PhilippM Thanks. Your comment made my day. That worked for me too